# Using map to change array elements other than the one currently being iterated

Tags: javascript, arrays

I really like the the way that Part1 is structured, but I've had to split part2 into part2 and part2array because it won't let me function chain.

```
const rawData = `Card 1: 41 48 83 86 17 | 83 86  6 31 17  9 48 53
 Card 2: 13 32 20 16 61 | 61 30 68 82 17 32 24 19
 Card 3:  1 21 53 59 44 | 69 82 63 72 16 21 14  1
 Card 4: 41 92 73 84 69 | 59 84 76 51 58  5 54 83
 Card 5: 87 83 26 28 32 | 88 30 70 12 93 22 82 36
 Card 6: 31 18 13 56 72 | 74 77 10 23 35 67 36 11`;

const cardObjects = (card) => {
  const cardNumber = card.match(/\d+(?=:)/)[0];
  const winningNumbers = card
    .match(/(?<=:)(.*?)(?=\|)/)[0]
    .trim()
    .split(/\s+/);
  const punterNumbers = card
    .match(/(?<=\|)(.*)/)[0]
    .trim()
    .split(/\s+/);
  return { cardNumber, winningNumbers, punterNumbers };
};

const punterWin = (card) => {
  const matchingNumber = card.winningNumbers.filter((w) =>
    card.punterNumbers.includes(w)
  );
  return matchingNumber;
};

const calculatePoints = (matchingNumber) => {
  const points = Math.pow(2, matchingNumber.length - 1);
  return points;
};

const cardWin = (wins, i) => {
  const winCount = wins.length;
  const card = i + 1;
  const cardCount = 1;
  return { card, cardCount, winCount };
};

const cardAdd = (cardWinCount, i) => {
  const winCount = cardWinCount.winCount;
  for (let x = 0; x < winCount; x++) {
    part2Array[i + x + 1].cardCount += cardWinCount.cardCount;
  }
};

const part1 = rawData
  .split(/\n/)
  .map(cardObjects)
  .map(punterWin)
  .map(calculatePoints)
  .filter((a) => a >= 1)
  .reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur);

console.log(part1);

const part2Array = rawData
  .split(/\n/)
  .map(cardObjects)
  .map(punterWin)
  .map(cardWin);

part2Array.forEach(cardAdd);

const part2 = part2Array
  .map((card) => card.cardCount)
  .reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur);

console.log(part2);
```

If I try and merge part2 with part2array then it doesn't work:

```
const part2 = rawData
  .split(/\n/)
  .map(cardObjects)
  .map(punterWin)
  .map(cardWin)
  .forEach(cardAdd)
  .map((card) => card.cardCount)
  .reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur);
```

This seems to be because I can't use map to change array elements other than the one currently being iterated unless that array is in a separate variable. Is there any way I can have a cleaner part2?

Comment: map is not to be used to mutate your original array in the first place, it creates a new array for you, if you want to change your original array, just use a forEach or a regular loop

Comment: It's possible to do what you want but not preferable. The chain becomes hard to reason about. To be honest, I don't even know why you'd define `cardAdd` - it changes the *next* `winCount` cards by adding `cardCount` to them. Presumably `winCount` can't cause the loop to go out of the array. This means that it's trivially equivalent to multiplication - instead of `{winCount: 3, cardCount: 5 }` causing the score would be calculated as `1 + 5, 2 + 5,  3 + 5` that can all just be added to the total as `winCount * cardCount` without needing to modify the rest of the cards.

Comment: the desired `.map(cardWin).forEach(cardAdd).map((card) => card.cardCount)` should be the same as `.map(cardWin).map((card) => card.cardCount * card.winCont)`

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with functional programming? This isn't the least bit pure. I've removed the functional programming tag.